# Chef new_resource.<value> vs. <value>

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I inherited a cookbook utilizing another cookbook with a custom resource.

I'm trying to figure out the use of the `new_resource` in this code.

In the code below, `path new_resource.fullpath` causes a "non-defined method."

When I changed that line to simply `path fullpath` to reference the local variable, it worked just fine. I can't figure out what the previous intent was.

I'm sure this is an easy one. Looking for an ELI5. Thanks!

Full code Block.

```
resource_name :mb_worker_role
default_action :create

property :service_name, String, name_property: true
property :root_path, String, required: true
property :executable, String, required: true
property :wcf_port, [Integer, String], default: 808
property :health_port, [Integer, String], default: 8000
property :use_dummy, [TrueClass, FalseClass], default: true

action :create do
  # Create firewall allow for WCF port
  windows_firewall_rule "#{new_resource.service_name} - WCF" do
    localport new_resource.wcf_port.to_s
    protocol 'TCP'
    firewall_action :allow
  end

  # Create firewall allow for health port
  windows_firewall_rule "#{new_resource.service_name} - Health" do
    localport new_resource.health_port.to_s
    protocol 'TCP'
    firewall_action :allow
  end

  # Full path to service executable at root_path\executable
  fullpath = "#{new_resource.root_path}\\#{new_resource.executable}"

  # Create directory for worker role application root
  directory new_resource.root_path do
    recursive true
    action :create
  end

  # Set NetTCPPortSharing to start on demand
  windows_service 'NetTCPPortSharing' do
    action :configure_startup
    startup_type :manual
  end

  # Stage the dummy worker role executable if requested
  # Only used to verify this resource when testing
  if property_is_set?(:use_dummy)
    cookbook_file 'Stage dummy worker role executable' do
      # path new_resource.fullpath
      path fullpath
      cookbook 'mb_worker_role'
      source 'WorkerRole.Default.exe'
      only_if { new_resource.use_dummy }
      action :create
    end
  end

  # Create windows service if it does not exist
  powershell_script "Installing Windows service #{new_resource.service_name}" do
    code <<-EOH
      # Create the Windows service
      sc.exe create "#{new_resource.service_name}" binPath="#{fullpath}"
    EOH
    not_if "(Get-Service -Name #{new_resource.service_name}).Name -eq '#{new_resource.service_name}'"
  end

  # Set service to automatic and make sure it's running
  windows_service new_resource.service_name do
    action [:configure_startup, :enable, :start]
    startup_type :automatic
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like the intent is for 'new_resource' to respond to a method called fullpath. I'm not sure from what you've put whether the problem is that you don't have a variable called 'new_resource', in which case it will say 'Undefined method fullpath for nilclass', or if the variable doesn't respond to that method, which will reference the class of new_resource in the error message

Comment: The issue with your change is you'll obviously be using the full_path variable which has already been defined, rather than what I'm guessing the author of that code intended, which is to use whatever value returns from new_resource.full_path

Comment: OK ignore the above 2 comments, I just saw the line: fullpath = "#{new_resource.root_path}\\#{new_resource.executable}"

Comment: From that it looks like what you've changed is correct, and that the new_resource object shouldn't be responding to full_path, but used to create the full_path variable in the line above

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm not sure what the original authors intent was, but with pull path being defined in the resource, what I changed appears to be the proper action.

Answer (score 0):

`path fullpath` is a magical alias system that we actively discourage at this point. It was a nice thing to try, but the syntax has a lot of problems that result in unexpected behavior. Use `new_resource.fullpath`, far fewer footguns.